# Is Google still giving weightage for old domain, i.e at least 6 month old?

Tags: seo, google, domains, google-adsense, search-engine-indexing

Is Google still giving weightage for old domain, i.e at least 6 months old?

I mean I have the best content which is useful for users.

Do I still have to wait for my domain name to be at least 6 months old?

Answer (score 3):

Matt Cutts in ["How much does a domain's age affect its ranking?"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1_1NQWQJ2Q) [YouTube]:

> "My short answer is not to worry about that very much. Not very much
>   at all, in fact."

Answer (score 3):

Search engines may give weight to *domain age* but I assure it is **nothing** compared to the *impact of the domain being that old*.

Since older domains have had more time to accumulate links and links are primordial to rankings, older domains frequently fair better compared to a newer competing domain.

One aspect is user habit formed by knowing a domain for a long time. In order to displace an older domain in the same market you need to have more that just better content but a vastly different angle on the same topic and, even so, so you be fighting upstream.

Answer (score 0):

Matt Cutts says a lot of things.  It is my experience that my aged domains perform better.  Having said that, I can not guarantee it is from the age or the amount of links the site has achieved over time, but I can say that I can pick up a new keyword on an aged domain much faster than a new domain.